# How do I remove the left column in finders column view?

Tags: finder, macos, folders, ui

When in column view in finder, there may be several columns displayed, one for each folder. Let's say the one I really care about is 5 folders deep, and so its far to the right side of the window. How can I make that folder the "root" of the column view window? Alternatively, how do I remove the left-most column/folder from being displayed?

Comment: Is there something in particular you are trying to accomplish? I don't know of a way to do exactly what you are asking, but maybe there is another way to go about it.

Comment: Sometimes I'm looking in a folder that contains files with long file names, and expanding the column to fit the file names will make the entire window wider. I start to run out of room on my screen, and shrinking the finder window while keeping the column width can be tricky and cumbersome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just drag your folder to the "Favorites" panel and it will be the root folder for that window. You can see the full path at the bottom, my folder (Mateus) is deep in the HD but the parent columns are not showing.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thanks! This is the only thing that has worked so far since I'm running **macOS Sierra**. I'll be upgrading to **macOS Mojave** soon, so I'll have to come back and try some other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this works in **macOS High Sierra** 10.13, but as mentioned in a comment does not work in **macOS Mojave** 10.14, and does not appear to work in **macOS Monterey** 12.6.  The second solution at the bottom appears to still work.

One of the ways I know how to have the *target folder* be the *left most column* while in **Column view** in **Finder** is to do the following:

1. While in **Column view**, highlight (*select*) the *target folder*.
2. Either press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> or right-click and select: **Open in New Tab**

The *root* of the new **Tab** in **Column view** will be that of the *selected folder* and you can close the now previous **Tab**, if you so choose.

---

The other way is to do as suggested in Mateus Ribeiro answer, add it to the **Sidebar**, as suggested, can be done by drag and drop.

Not mentioned in his answer, but another way is after highlighting (*selecting*) the *target folder* press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to add it to the **Sidebar**.

Comment: On Mojave this isn't quite right. You do get a truncated hierarchy, but the left-most column is the parent of the folder originally highlighted.

Comment: @samh, Hence why I explicitly stated, "Note that this works for me in macOS High Sierra and I have not tested it in other versions of macOS" The OP doesn't mention what version of macOS is being used.

Comment: Hence, why I’m including info on other versions of Mac OS.

Comment: Thanks for all the solutions! I'm running macOS Sierra right now. **Open in New Tab** is not an option after right-clicking, and Control Command O opens the _target folder_ in a new window, but without it being the left-most column.  **File > New Tab** doesn't put the _target folder_ on the left either. Control Command T adds the _target folder_ to the **Sidebar**. After that, I can use the **Sidebar** to open the _target folder_ as the left-most column in a new window.

Comment: This answer should be deleted since it no longer works.

Comment: @JimGarrison Deleting it would then be of no use for High Sierra users who may be searching for a solution, even in 2021. Just cos something doesn't work on the current macOS version doesn't make it a candidate for deletion.